# Google cloud run sudden latency spikes and container instance time increase

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-run, knative

We are having recurring problems with our container instances with python running on cloud run. We currently have 20 services deployed, which run fine weeks at a time and then get sudden spikes in request latency as well as ping checks failing and the container instance time going up. We cannot see any added traffic during these spells of longer latency in our systems. Common access points such as database and cache all seem normal.

The region is europe-west1

Does anyone have any tips on what to check? Our have experienced similar problems?

Latency:
[image]

Container instance time:
[image]

Comment: this should be a support ticket and region is important information

Comment: Added region. We will escalate this if we dont get any valid responses here, and feedback the answer here if this happens.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I agree with Pentium10, this should be handled by [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) as they would have the proper tools to analyze your project and determine if there is something wrong with it, or if it is a bug in that particular region.

Comment: I highly doubt anyone here can solve it for you. If it happens to ALL of your different services, you should definitely contact support. If some services (e.g. written in other languages) don’t exhibit this, then it's more likely to be in your code (such as a build-up or a leak)

Comment: I have opened a support request with Google and will supply the answer I get from them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to buy support for Google Cloud to get a good answer to this. They told me to make adjustment to my cloud service instances, but none to any effect. They later admitted that this was due to a problem on their end. It is a shame that you as a user do not get any feedback on problems like these when using the Google Cloud Platform, a simple notification in the Google Cloud console for affected users would be of great help, but I think they may like to cover these things up as to not worsen the service accessibility numbers.